# Trying to concatenate binary numbers into one value

Tags: c, arrays, binary, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate integers by turning them into a string, then turning them back into an integer to put it into one string/integer. I'm using a concatenation example, which I got from google, but it doesn't seem to work and I have no idea why.

I've tried some other concatenation examples but they didn't work either. Also tried `x*10` and `x+y`, since I'm working with single digit numbers/binary.

This is my concatenation function:

```c
int concat(int a, int b)
{

    char s1[20];
    char s2[20];

    sprintf(s1, "%d", a);
    sprintf(s2, "%d", b);

    strcat(s1, s2);

    int c = atoi(s1);

    return c;
}
```

and this is the rest

```c
for (i = 0; i < countr+1; i++)
    {
        b = theArr[i];
        r = 0;
        count = 0;
        if (b < 0) 
        {
            tempval = (unsigned int)b;
            while (tempval != 0) 
            {
                n = tempval % 2;
                tempval /= 2;
                m[r] = n;
                count += 1; r++;
            }

            for (k = count - 1; k >= 0; k--) 
            {
                printf("%d", m[k]);
                if (tempC == 0) 
                {
                    testOutput = m[k];
                    tempC++;
                }
                else
                {
                    testOutput = concat(testOutput, m[k]);
                }
            }
            tempC = 0;
            printf("\nHERE:%d\n", testOutput);
            printf("\n");
        }
            else 
            {
                while (b != 0) 
                {
                    n = b % 2;
                    b /= 2;
                    m[r] = n;
                    count += 1; r++;
                }

            for (k = count - 1; k >= 0; k--) 
            {
                printf("%d", m[k]);
                printf("%d", m[k]);
                if (tempC == 0)
                {
                    testOutput = m[k];
                    tempC++;
                }
                else
                {
                    testOutput = concat(testOutput, m[k]);
                }
            }
            tempC = 0;
            printf("\nHERE:%d\n", testOutput);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

In array "m" there is either a 1 or a 0 in each slot. I'm trying to add it together so for example:

```
if m[10] = {0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1};
"testOutput" would be "0101100011"
```

my Float value is: `271459.593750` and it spits back out: `1240481687`

Edit: `theArr` has float numbers in it.

Comment: You're going to encounter an overflow with certain inputs, and you'll lose any leading zeroes when converting to an `int`

Comment: That's a very inefficient way of doing it... and what do you mean by float value? What variables here are floats? If it's a float you cant print it with `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You are getting overflow in `atoi`

Assuming that your system has 32 bits `int` and use 2's complement representation, the maximum value that can be stored in an `int` is 2147483647. For the way you want the result your maximum will be 1111111111, i.e. 10 digits. In other words - when the concatenated string has 11 (or more) digits the `atoi` no longer produce the expected result.

Inserting this print

```
printf("concatenated string \"%s\" gives c=%d\n", s1, c);
```

just before the `return c;` gives this output:

```
concatenated string "10" gives c=10
concatenated string "100" gives c=100
concatenated string "1000" gives c=1000
concatenated string "10000" gives c=10000
concatenated string "100001" gives c=100001
concatenated string "1000010" gives c=1000010
concatenated string "10000100" gives c=10000100
concatenated string "100001001" gives c=100001001
concatenated string "1000010010" gives c=1000010010
concatenated string "10000100100" gives c=1410165508  // Notice the overflow !!
concatenated string "14101655080" gives c=1216753192
concatenated string "12167531921" gives c=-717369967
concatenated string "-7173699671" gives c=1416234921
concatenated string "14162349210" gives c=1277447322
concatenated string "12774473220" gives c=-110428668
concatenated string "-1104286680" gives c=-1104286680
concatenated string "-11042866801" gives c=1842035087
concatenated string "18420350871" gives c=1240481687

HERE:1240481687
```

You can try to use `long long int` instead of `int` and use `atoll` instead of `atoi`. That will help you store some extra digits.